# When I load the react native navigation package for the first time, I get this error during compilation

Tags: react-native, build, navigation

An error occurred while launching the application. Unknown error: not all success patterns were matched.
It means that "react-native run-android" command failed.
Please, check the View -> Toggle Output -> React Native,
View -> Toggle Output -> React Native: Run android output windows. (error code 712) (error code 303)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w71rJ.jpg)